# List::Util object version 1.38 does not match bootstrap parameter 1.41 at

Tags: perl

I'm using my local perl 5.20.1 and there is system perl 5.10.1. When installing Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.40, I received an error:

t/all.t .. List::Util object version 1.38 does not match bootstrap parameter 1.41 at ***/List/Util.pm line 22.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: BTW: I can't remove the old List::Util since I'm not the root.

Comment: I use perlbrew, to keep the system perl installation and my local installation completely separated. That works perfectly for me...

Comment: Another solution is to use [`local::lib`](http://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) and set `PERL5LIB` so you can manage your own set of modules separately from those installed system wide by the root user. –

Comment: Both solutions can solve my problem. Thank you very much.